# Unique solution of $(L+\alpha I)z=y$

Tags: operator-theory

Let $L:X \rightarrow X$ be a bounded linear operator with bounded-inverse.

How we can show that $(L+\alpha I) z= y $ has a unique solution for sufficiently small $\vert \alpha \vert$?

If $Lx=y$, find a bound for $\Vert z - x \Vert$ in terms of $\vert \alpha \vert$,$\Vert L \Vert$, $\Vert L^{-1} \Vert$, and $\Vert y \Vert$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok a misread the inequality you wanted so let me rewrite another proof.

We start from the following theorem:

Let $f \in \mathcal{L}(X,X)$ such that $||f|| < 1$, then $Id - f$ is invertible and $||Id-(Id-f)^{-1}|| \leq \frac{||f||}{1-||f||}$. You can find this theorem for example in the book of Jean Saint Raymond, Topologie calcul differentiel et variable complexe > http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~jean.saint-raymond/preprints/TopoCD.pdf page 50 theorem 6.4.9

So what we have is $ L+\alpha Id = L\circ(Id + \alpha L^{-1})= L\circ(Id - -\alpha L^{-1})$ So according to the theorem $ Id - -\alpha L^{-1}$ is invertible for any $\alpha<\frac{1}{||L^{-1}||}$ and so will be $ L+\alpha Id =L\circ(Id - -\alpha L^{-1})$.

Then $||x-z||= || (L^{-1} - (L+\alpha Id)^{-1})y|| \leq ||(L^{-1} - (L+\alpha Id)^{-1})|| ||y||$ and noting that

$||L^{-1} - (L+\alpha Id)^{-1}||=||L^{-1} - (L\circ(Id - -\alpha L^{-1}))^{-1}||=||L^{-1} - (Id - -\alpha L^{-1})^{-1}\circ L^{-1}||=||(Id - (Id - -\alpha L^{-1})^{-1})\circ L^{-1}|| \leq \alpha\frac{||L^{-1}||^2}{1-||\alpha L^{-1}||}$

Comment: It's very nice proof. but where I can find that book in English?

Comment: I don't think you can find it in english unfortunately, but maybe you can find the result in a other english book, or also if there is something in the proof of the result you happen to not understand I can translate it for you.